# How to merge the second vector to the first, but from a predefined different position, not from continuation?

Tags: arrays, matlab

Suppose I initialized two vectors,

```
x=[1 2 3 4 5]';
y=[6 7 8 9 10]';
```

both representing a column matrix, or vector. Now,

```
z=[x;y];
```

The `z` vector will be combination of the two, in a similar column format. `y` vector will be in continuation to the `x` vector by this method.

But what should be the approach if I wanted `y` to be in continuation from a certain given position, leaving the remaining values in between as blank. For example, I want the continuation of `y` from 8th position to get an output of `z` as:-

```
1
2
3
4
5
NaN
NaN
6
7
8
9
10
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just count, how many blanks (`NaN`) do you need using the desired position and the number of elements of `x`, and assemble your output `z`:

```matlab
% Input
x = [1 2 3 4 5]'
y = [6 7 8 9 10]'

% Position
pos = 8;

% Add some code for checking numel(x) >= pos here...

% Output
z = [x; NaN(pos-numel(x)-1, 1); y]

x =
   1
   2
   3
   4
   5

y =
    6
    7
    8
    9
   10

z =
     1
     2
     3
     4
     5
   NaN
   NaN
     6
     7
     8
     9
    10
```

---

Meh, after some editing, I realized, that a comment would've been sufficient...

Comment: See, that's why I always emphasize to go through every aspect and part of a programming language. I recently shifted from FORTRAN to MATLAB for some work. For the same problem I asked, I was planning to go through loops, however, you solved it by short method of array indexing. By the time I saw your answer, I had already developed that looping method in MATLAB, and tested it to work correctly. Your answer, however, gave me some different insight which I didn't knew from before. Tnx!